# How do I run all @DataJpaTest classes at once?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test, springrunner

I am able to run each `@DataJpaTest` separately from eclipse.

My `@DataJpaTest` is something like below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(UserDataOnDemand.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
public class UserIntegrationTest {

......

}
```

Is there any way to run all `@DataJpaTest` classes at once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options really.

1. Include all the tests in the same package and run all the tests in that package.
2. Include all your @DataJpaTest annotated classes in a test suite class and run this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ DataJpaTest1.class, DataJpaTest2.class })
public class MyTestSuite {
}
```

Comment: I tried option 2 and its working as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept my answer if it worked!